# SQL Server. Allow multiple values throwing error Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value … to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Newbie here. Attempting to allow report to run multiple values when being run but above error happens when selecting multiple. Any help will be appreciated.

```
where ContactActivityNoteType.ClientId = 1
and ContactActivityNoteType.ContactActivityNoteTypeId in (13, 4, 22)
and tc.ContactTypeId = 2
and ca.EnteredOn between @start_date and @end_date
and ca.ClientAccountId in (@ClientAccountId)
```

Comment: You can not pass a multi valued, comma separated varchar directly to an in clause as a parameter. This is a well researched topic some googling would of given you answers for. Try http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html

Comment: Should have said, the issue is coming from the clientaccountid

Comment: @Pரதீப் rather useless to post code for a non-existent function when the OP is a newbie. What they are referring to here is the need for a string split function. Here is my favorite. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/ Or several other excellent here. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: @SeanLange - Make sense.. removed..

Comment: You can pass multi-valued parameters directly and use them in an IN clause as long as your dataset query contains the the actual query, not a call to a Stored Procedure. SSRS will take you parameter values and build a dynamic SQL statement injecting your values as a comma separated list then execute the SQL. There is no need to use JOIN/SPLIT etc in this scenario. 

@rjricketts Can you update your post to include the details of your parameter, is it a list of values typed in or form a query? What types are the Value and Label fields assigned in the parameter properties? etc.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to change your multi-valued parameter to a temporary table and then join that temp table to your main table.

*In your query based dataset, you can do this part before main query.*

For example, if following is your multi-valued variable:

```
DECLARE @ClientAccountId VARCHAR(MAX) = 'a10001,a10002,a10003,a10004'
```

You can use the following chunk of SQL code to change it to a temp table:

```
CREATE TABLE #ClientAccountIds (ClientAccountId  VARCHAR(30));
DECLARE @Insert VARCHAR(MAX) = 'INSERT INTO #ClientAccountIds VALUES ('''+REPLACE(@ClientAccountId,',','''),(''')+''');';
EXEC (@Insert);
```

So that following SQL:

```
SELECT ClientAccountId FROM #ClientAccountIds
```

will return:

[image]

And now you can easily join this temporary table to your main query.

Hope this help?